# Determining if a file DOES NOT exist

Tags: php, file-io

I have some code which seems logical but is not working as expected.

```
<?php
$ukip_code = "PTXC";

$show_logo = "http://www.ukipme.com/img/confs/" . strtolower($ukip_code) . ".gif";

echo $show_logo . "<br>";

echo "<img src=" . $show_logo . "><br>";

if (!file_exists($show_logo)) { // or file_exists($show_logo) === false
    $show_logo = "http://placehold.it/165x100/&text={$ukip_code}";
}

echo $show_logo;
?>
```

My first `echo` shows the original file's URL. I then `echo` an `img` tag to prove that this file is an actual file.

I then check if the file exists, and if it does not, use a placeholder image. `Echo`ing this variable now *should* give the original URL again (as it quite clearly does exist), but it gives the placeholder URL. Why?

I've also tried using `file_exists($show_logo) === false` in my `if` statement, but I get the same result.

Comment: `file_exists` works on files, not on URLs.

Comment: `file_exists` function require your local directory path like `/home/sk/public_hmtl..` not http urls

Comment: Great thanks, I'll modify my code. Is there a way I **can** make a check via URL?

Comment: @mpdc You could use get_headers and check the response code, a response of 200-299 is fine, a response of 400+ indicates an error of some kind(300 is redirects, 100 is partial responses and you shouldn't see them using this function).

Comment: use physical path to the file rather then file URL

Comment: Is the file (supposed to be) located on the local server, or at a remote location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_headers()` method to get the status of the resource:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

```
$regex = "(200|201|203|204|205|206)";

$headers = get_headers($show_logo);

preg_match($regex, $headers[0], $match);

if (!$match) {
   $show_logo = "http://placehold.it/165x100/&text={$ukip_code}";
}

echo $show_logo;
```

Comment: Just a quick warning, but 201(created to fulfil request), and 202(accepted, processing will continue in the background) are both perfectly acceptable response code to indicate success, just because 200 is the most common doesn't mean it's the only success code that may be used.

Comment: @scragar thanks, you are right. Edited my example regarding 10.2 in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the server path to the site, not the url of the site. Something like `/home/etc/file_name`

Your var should be like this

```
$show_logo = "/{the site server path}/img/confs/" . strtolower($ukip_code) . ".gif";
```

if you need `__FILE__` constant will give you absolute path to current file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read in the contents which is behind the url. The drawback however is that this will generate some traffic for big images. But it makes sure that if the file can be downloaded from the given url that it is available. There is curl_setopt which could give you some more options.

```
<?php
$ukip_code = "PTXC";
$opt = FALSE;

$show_logo = "http://www.ukipme.com/img/confs/" . strtolower($ukip_code) . ".gif";

echo $show_logo . "<br>";

echo "<img src=" . $show_logo . "><br>";

// Create a curl session
$ch = curl_init($show_logo);

// Execution
curl_exec($ch);

// Verification if an error occured
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch, $opt);
}

// Fermeture du gestionnaire
curl_close($ch);


if ($opt === FALSE) {
    $show_logo = "http://placehold.it/165x100/&text={$ukip_code}";
}

echo $show_logo;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this -

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sitepathtofile';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    set the placeholder
}
```